# Erro de textura no opengl

Tags: c, opengl, sdl

Estou tentando fazer umas coisas em C usando o SDL e o opengl, e na hora de desenhar texturas eu consigo facilmente se quiser apenas 1 objeto com textura porem ao tentar colocar uma textura no fundo e outra pra qualquer objeto ambas as texturas estao sendo renderizadas com a textura do fundo, queria saber se alguem sabe o por que e possa me ajudar com isso.

codigo em https://codeshare.io/jogo_andrew:main.c .

Answer (score 0):

`unsigned int object; // cria textura
    glGenTextures(1, &object); // gera textura`

nesse trecho a função 'glGenTextures' gera um referência para uma área de armazenamento para uma textura, sempre que vc chama sua função de alocar textura, ela sobreescreve a referência para essa área de armazenamento.

Para resolver vc precisa de uma estrutura de dados (lista ou array por exemplo) para guardar todas as referências geradas pelo 'glGenTextures'.

Comment: Poderia dar um exemplo de como iria ficar ?